# discard input when dismissing keyboard with tap

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have some textfields in multiple views, and I want to be able to discard any input (i.e. don't do anything with what has been typed) if the user taps outside the keyboard to dismiss it.

As suggested in some posts I did the following

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

and I call `self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()` in the `viewDidLoad()` method of any view controller where I want this behaviour.

what happens is that whenever the keyboard is dismissed, the code I have in `textFieldDidEndEditing` is executed. I don't want to do that, because errors are triggered if the input is not a correct one, but the user dismissed the keyboard as a way to step back, not to send the input.

I thought that `view.endEditing(true)` just called `resignFirstResponder()` on every subview but apparently also `textFieldDidEndEditing()` gets called.
How do I avoid it?

I have been looking around a lot of posts on SO but I could find a reason on how to solve the problem.
I might also be approaching the question in a wrong way.

Comment: feels like the user should do something(button) to confirm the end of a edit and not just tap out of the keyboard

Comment: Your `textFieldDidEndEditing` will always be called, because, well, editing *did* end.  You could do something like `myTextField.text = nil` in `dismissKeyboard()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to understand my mistake.

The logic/code for handling the input should go in the `textFieldShouldReturn()` method, which is what is called when the return button of the keyboard is pressed.
This method is not called if the user dismisses the keyboard, because no return button has been called.

As @Moshe said, it is correct that the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method is called, because editing did end.

By just placing the logic for handling input from here to the other method, the problem was solved.

Sorry for the noob question, but I feel it could be of help to all the other beginners out there.